# OpenCV python environment set up on Mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv, curl

I am trying to set up OpenCV environmnet on my Mac El Capitan 10.11.5 using this tutorial: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

I constantly get en error: The source directory "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON" does not exist.

My curl command is:

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D          PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON`

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I found another way to get started here:
http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/
It seems to be working, but I am still not sure why the prevoius one would not go through.

Answer (score 0):

I had that Problem too, but in the end

`brew install opencv3 --with-python3`

did the trick for me.